# how to concat two different plots (an igraph and matplotlib plot) - python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn, igraph

I made a plot uisng igraph with this code:

```
ig.plot( test , bbox=(800,800), margin = 20,
        vertex_color = [color_dict1[vl] for vl in test.vs["cluster_id"]],
        edge_curved=True, edge_color= 'silver',
        vertex_size= 6,
       layout='fr', target=ax)
```

The first result:
[network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AcelO.png)

And, I made a legend plot of Top cluster ids using this code:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(1,1))
plt.axis('off')
plt.rcParams["font.family"] = "serif"

for cl,col,perc in list(list_cl_perc1[:20]):
    plt.scatter([],[], c=col, label='Cluster {} ({}%)'.format(int(cl),perc), s=300, figure=fig)
#legend_x = 1
#legend_y = 1  #bbox_to_anchor=(legend_x, legend_y)
plt.legend(title= 'Top 20 Clusters',loc='best',prop={'size': 17},
           ncol=1,title_fontsize=17 ,frameon=False, framealpha=1)
plt.savefig('legend.png', bbox_inches='tight', dpi=100)
plt.show()
```

[legend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6e5yD.png)

After I concat this two result using:

```
import sys
from PIL import Image

images = [Image.open(x) for x in ['plots.png', 'legend.png']]
widths, heights = zip(*(i.size for i in images))

total_width = sum(widths)
max_height = max(heights)

new_im = Image.new('RGB', (total_width, max_height))

x_offset = 0
for im in images:
  new_im.paste(im, (x_offset,0))
  x_offset += im.size[0]

new_im.save('test.jpg')
```

The result after 'concat':
[final](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zSRy.jpg)

I want know if there is a solution about 'how to concat these plots without export'

Comment: Have a look at the igraph documentation. Relevant section [here](https://igraph.org/python/doc/tutorial/visualisation.html#plotting-graphs-within-matplotlib-figures).

Comment: Yes , I read  but there isn't any about legends using igraphs.

Comment: You will have to probably have to create the legend yourself using proxy artists. Guide [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/legend_guide.html#proxy-legend-handles).